# May we see the overall citation stats for Documentation so far?

Tags: discussion, documentation

If I understand correctly, users are encouraged to cite useful examples from Documentation in their answers.

Given this fact, I think it would be interesting to look at the overall Docs citation stats. I failed to find any corresponding information on example pages themselves, so I assume that these numbers are not available publicly, at least currently.

Still, I think such stats would prove to be a useful metric of the actual utility of Documentation at this point. So, could someone with access to such data at least provide a current snapshot of the situation, including:

- Number of examples, which were cited at least once (to compare with the total number of examples).
- Mean, median and max number of citations per example across all examples.
- Number of citations, compared to number of upvotes per example (would be especially interesting to see the percentage for `"Creating and initializing arrays"`<sup>1</sup>, seeing as it is the most upvoted)

It might also be useful to separately calculate these stats for citations, where the person citing is not one of the editors of the example being cited (i.e. doesn't have a personal stake).

I'm not a statistician, so it's hard for me to say which numbers would be the most informative, so, if you have any suggestions, please post them in the comments, I'll update the question.

---

<sup>1</sup>I would give you a link, but I don't want to accidentally distort the stats by providing what might qualify as a citation of this example here. You all know where to find it anyway.

Comment: It has only been available for a week with limited content. Isn't it a bit premature to expect any meaningful data?

Comment: @charlietfl *"It has only been available for a week with limited content."* We can keep this in mind when we analyze the data. *"Isn't it a bit premature to expect any meaningful data."* I don't think so. Even if a snapshot in a week or two might be more informative, I think even this early such stats would give us, at least in very broad strokes, the measurement of Documentation's positive impact *(or, maybe, lack thereof)*. I.e., whether it looks like Documentation is turning out to be the best thing since peanut butter or not.

Comment: @TerraPass - You're going to make the determination if it's as good as peanut butter after one week?  Heck no this is way too early.  Sorry pal -1.

Comment: "As good as peanut butter"? What does that even mean?

Comment: There are a couple of citation related badges which as of now have been awarded only 568 times. So, the citation count should be very less (may not even be half) considering the fact that all users who have contributed to an example/topic will get the badge when it is cited. Must be more than 56 surely because the Creditor badge has been awarded that many times.

Comment: This is a bit amusing considering that [some of us still don't know how cite documentation answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328540/210780)!

Comment: @DanielMargosian you don't remember when peanut butter came along? The whole game changed.

Comment: @DanielMargosian That's what Documentation is advertised as in its tour page: peanut butter to Q&A's chocolate (implying that they go well together).

Comment: @TerraPass Ok? Why is everyone focused on this analogy

Comment: @DanielMargosian Well, I do have other analogies for what Documentation is, but I'm afraid SO dev team won't really appreciate them.

Comment: I'd expect citations to be the most lagging of any metric (compared to, say, active users, topics, edits, views, etc), and therefore the one that's least informative after only a week. In 6-8 months it may be interesting

Comment: While I agree it's too early to analyze the data and get meaningful results, now is exactly the right time to start collecting such statistics so that when the data is actually interesting one can analyze it. So +1 for the proposal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm surprised nobody thought of this earlier, but you can easily find which posts link to Documentation. It's not anything new actually, just [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/519588/find-documentation).

Keep in mind that the data may be up to a week out of date; SEDE is updated weekly on Sundays.

To get 100 posts that link to anything on Documentation, you can use:

```sql
select top 100 
  id as [Post Link]
 ,body
from posts 
where body like '%"http://stackoverflow.com/documentation%'
```

(It's not terribly efficient, but it's a start at least.)

I don't see any way to get any information about Documentation (such as who wrote what), but hopefully that will be added at some point.

Comment: Wow. I've actually never heard of this tool. Thank you for the link and the query, that's indeed a start and I think it'll have to do for now, until more data on the Docs becomes available.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use Stack Overflow search, which is up-to-date most of the time unlike Data Explorer.

```
url:"https://stackoverflow.com/documentation"
```

[link to the search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fdocumentation%22)