# Let's award no reputation to contributors, when a Documentation example they contributed to gets upvoted

Tags: feature-request, documentation, reputation

As you probably know, at the moment each upvote, received by a Documentation example, rewards each person, who edited this example, with **+5 reputation**, regardless of whether there is 1 editor or 100, regardless of whether this particular editor's contribution even has anything left of it in the current version of the example, regardless of whether this even was a useful edit or an act of vandalism or plagiarism, whose sole objective was to get its author on the rep train, in the first place.

This is widely regarded<sup>1</sup> as a mockery of StackOverflow's reputation system. Indeed, a cynical observer might even say that Docs rep rewards look like they have been specifically designed this way in order to "buy" early activity and a high volume of contributions in the public beta, with no regard for the actual quality of said contributions.

I'm not a cynic, personally, so I'll leave it up to the readers of the present feature request to make up their own minds as to whether such point of view is warranted.

Whatever the case may be, due to the current state of things, there have lately been a number of suggestions as to how to improve Docs rep distribution system, especially the part concerning reputation rewards for upvotes. [Some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329506/1051764) users think that it would be best to allocate a total number of rep points per upvote, which would be shared between editors, according to the impact of each edit. [Others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329940/can-we-please-introduce-more-reputation-limits-for-examples-on-documentation) suggest the introduction of some caps or limits for reputation, which may be gained from upvotes. [Still others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328866/dont-give-me-reputation-points-for-making-an-edit-to-a-documentation-topic) propose to drop any rewards for upvotes entirely. Meanwhile, [the developers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse) say that *"reputation rewards are here to stay"*.

Well, I'm pleased to announce that, using my powers of basic arithmetic, I've come up with a number, which, if set as the number of rep points per user for each example upvote, is going to satisfy everybody involved! What is this special number?

### It's 0.

*"Wait, what? That's nonsense!"* - I hear you exclaim, *"How will changing **+5 rep** to **+0** improve the situation, let alone reconcile all of the points of view on the subject?"* I'm glad you asked...

**It will automatically share the reward, according to the value of each editor's contribution.**

With this change in place, rewards will get distributed fairly without the need for complex attribution algorithms or asking the upvoter to manually distribute the reward among all of the 512 editors by tweaking 512 different sliders.

Consider an example. Let's say Alice has posted a splendid new example with just a few inaccuracies. Someone upvotes it and Alice, being the only contributor, gets +0 rep points, that is, the entire 100% of the reward. Then Bob contributes a useful edit, in which he corrects the inaccuracies in the original version by Alice. Example gets upvoted again. This time Alice gets +0 rep and Bob gets +0 rep (70% and 30%, respectively).

Then Charlie comes along. He's here just for teh reps, so he makes a minor change, which contributes barely anything of value to the example. But don't  worry, for every subsequent upvote to this example, all Charlie is going to get is meager +0 rep, 1% of the total reward.

See, it's like magic or something! And you can trust these numbers: I've double checked all of the math involved.

**Further contributions won't take away potential rewards from earlier contributors.**

In case of a reward sharing scheme with other values, such as +10 rep per upvote, suggested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330130/in-documentation-a-vote-should-be-worth-a-total-of-10-reputation-points-divided), Alice would be annoyed at Bob and, especially, Charlie, because after their contributions, she'd start getting less reputation per upvote, than when she was the only contributor.

Now, however, she'll get the same +0 rep as before. Alice is happy, and everybody is happy.

**Edits, which have been subsequently undone, will be handled automatically.**

One of the problems with the current system, is that it doesn't handle cases where an edit has been undone by further edits: contributors, not one character of whose edits has made it to the current version of the example, still get +5 per upvote. Solving this problem would have required huge efforts by the SO dev team, as they would have had to come up with a sophisticated algorithm to track such edits.

They would have... but they don't need to! See, if this feature-request gets accepted, authors of undone/overwritten edits will automatically stop getting any rep points from the upvotes.

That's right! Going back to our example, imagine Dara comes over and makes a change, within scope of which she, among a couple of other things, overwrites Charlie's changes completely. Example gets upvoted again. Previously, Charlie would get as much as 0 rep for the upvote, now he gets nothing.

***"Reputation rewards are here to stay"***

The devs appear to be hesitant when it comes to removing the reward for example upvotes. So, the best thing about this suggestion, is that they don't have to!

I mean, we can even keep all of the fanfare! Imagine navigating to a different page on StackOverflow and seeing the achievements icon light up with familiar green color. *"+0"* it says, and as you click it to reveal the breakdown of upvotes, which the examples you edited have received, your soul is filled with that warm and fuzzy feeling of having helped someone in the community to get their "Backer" badge for the first example upvote.

**Example upvotes will no longer reward editors with reputation.**

This one is pretty self-explanatory, so I won't dwell on it.

**Easy to implement.**

No monstrous attribution algorithms, no fiddly limits and daily caps, no arbitrary definitions of what does and does not constitute a "substantial edit". Just one integer constant to change in the code (config file, database?) *et **voilà*** - we are in a brave new world!

### All kidding aside...

...I think that removing rep awards for Docs upvotes will be beneficial for both Q&A and Documentation. On the Q&A side of things, it will stop devaluing existing and discouraging future contributions by putting an end to the flood of disproportionately cheap reputation. As for the Docs, it will remove most of the me-too editors and leave only the people who actually wish to make a useful addition or edit. While the volume of contributions would drop, their average quality would rise.

These people would still be rewarded for producing useful content via "royalty" reputation from citations in Q&A (though I don't yet have [the data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330064/may-we-see-the-overall-citation-stats-for-documentation-so-far) to back this prediction up). While "royalty" itself suffers from similar problems, their impact on the overall ecosystem is much less pronounced.

---

1 <sub>Concerns regarding Documentation's rep train not having any brakes, as it were, have already been expressed many times and by many people. While they provide context for this feature request, I'd like to abstain from rehashing all of the discussion. Therefore, I'll just give a couple of links to previous Meta posts, which highlight problems with the current system far more eloquently than I ever could:</sub>

- [Don't give me reputation points for making an edit to a Documentation topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328866/dont-give-me-reputation-points-for-making-an-edit-to-a-documentation-topic)
- [Can we please introduce more reputation limits for examples on Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329940/can-we-please-introduce-more-reputation-limits-for-examples-on-documentation)
- [Documentation shares the work: make the rewards shared, not multiplicative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329506/1051764) (also see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329736/1051764) answer by Erwin Brandstetter)

---

**P. S.** I solemnly ask moderators and other users not to get trigger-happy with designating this question as a duplicate of any of the related posts, even if you happen to disagree with the point of view and the suggestion expressed in it.

Here is why this question is **not** a duplicate:

- It's not a duplicate of "[Don't give me reputation points for making an edit to a Documentation topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328866/dont-give-me-reputation-points-for-making-an-edit-to-a-documentation-topic)", because that post is a discussion and not a direct feature request.
- It's not a duplicate of "[Can we please introduce more reputation limits for examples on Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329940/can-we-please-introduce-more-reputation-limits-for-examples-on-documentation)" or "[Documentation shares the work: make the rewards shared, not multiplicative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329506/1051764)", because this feature-request suggests a different solution for the problem, than either of these two suggest.
- It's not a duplicate of "[Addressing Documentation #RepGateApocalypse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse)", because that post is basically a status report by a SO dev, expressing their current stance on the problem and asking for input. How can you even close a **feature request** as a duplicate of that?
- It's not a duplicate of a somewhat similar feature request by `@luweiqi`<strike>, which was itself hastily (and, in my opinion, unfairly) closed as a duplicate of "[Addressing Documentation #RepGateApocalypse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse)"</strike>*(looks like it's been reopened)*. The solution I offer in this feature-request is more focused: I suggest exactly one way to address the problem and this way is different from either of the two solutions, presented by `@luweiqi`.

More importantly, though, in my humble opinion, it would be great if the community could, at last, hear a direct response from the devs as to whether they are prepared to go this way and, either now or later down the line, remove this particular source of reputation. (We would still have rep awards for edits getting approved and "royalty" rep for edited examples getting cited in Q&A.)

<strike>There currently is no other open feature-request, which outright proposes to remove reputation gains from upvotes.</strike> *(this is no longer true, since [a similar feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330108/reduce-or-dont-award-reputation-for-docs-upvotes) by `@luweiqi` has been reopened)* Not to introduce limits, not to award variable number of rep ponts, but to simply make each upvote worth 0. This is why, I think many users would really appreciate it if we could see a definitive `status-declined` or `status-deferred` or `status-planned` marker on this feature request.

Thank you.

Comment: +1 example totally reflects the current situation ;-)

Comment: "While the volume of contributions would drop, their average quality would rise." I don't know how something so simple, eludes the many.

Comment: "*While the volume of contributions would drop, their average quality would rise.*" I don't see how that follows. Or at least, I don't see how that is *guaranteed* to follow. The volume of contributions to the OpenGL Wiki was semi-high initially, but then fell off to almost nothing. But the quality of contributions did not rise until I made improving the Wiki my personal hobby. Had I not chosen to do so, and had nobody else taken up the mantle, it would still be a disorganized mass of useless crap, assuming they didn't just delete it due to uselessness.

Answer (score 9):

I do not see your argument that giving 0 rep points would *increase* the quality of edits. If anything it would decrease the overall amount of edits, regardless if they are good or bad. I fear that would lead to stagnation and ultimate abandonment of Documentation.

Moreover, people with significant edit in mind may gravitate to actually create a separate topic to be credited for their work. As a result it may lead to unnecessary duplication of topics.

The problem is that the Documentation, by design, relies much more on edits than the typical Q&A format of SO.

I just stumbled on an example which was de-facto a stub. There were about 3 sentences total. I spend over an hour to change that into a full-blown explanation of the topic at hand. You now tell me I should not be rewarded for that action at all, but the author of the stub should take all the credit? If we go that route, maybe we should remove all reputation whatsoever then?

Comment: *"...but the author of the stub should take all the credit?"* That's not really what I had in mind. Maybe using the word "editor" was a mistake on my part. Anyway, in my scenario, *neither of you* would get rep from upvotes. (But both of you would still get rewarded for citations.)

Comment: "If we go that route, maybe we should remove all reputation whatsoever then?" Not a bad idea, actually.

Comment: So what was your motivation for doing the edit in the first place? Rep, or making it right?

Comment: @charlietfl Making it right is my main motivator, but rep is a nice secondary motivator/reward to it. People like to be recognized for their work you know.