# Documentation on SE Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, documentation, data-explorer

I've noticed that the new Documentation feature is nowhere to be seen on the SEDE, or is missing from the SO database schema, and I had a few queries I wanted to make for it. Can this be added?

Comment: I noticed this too [answering this related question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330196/6083675)

Comment: There's no point adding it until they are fairly comfortable that the schema for it has been fairly solidified. You may find this feature will be [meta-tag:status-deferred].