# Downloading Documentation dump

Tags: discussion, documentation

Is there any way to download a dump of the Documentation? (just like [we can do](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) for Stack Exchange websites).

To be clear:  I don't want to download just one page as a PDF (like the supposedly dupe question asks for), but all the documentation, ideally in a more machine-readable format.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330195/documentation-on-se-data-explorer

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks, I don't want to download just one page as a PDF like the OP in the question you pointed to, but all the documentation in a more machine-readable format.

Comment: @Laurel's comment on the duplicate is to look in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213 and find the section for *offline reference*, which is the answer, as it stands today.  It's on the future feature list for documentation.